# Method cache corrupted. This may be a message to an invalid object, or a memory error somewhere else

Tags: c, sdl

I'm writing a program for a uni project called turtles, where the user basically enters a series of commands into a text file (forward 30, right 20, etc) and the program then draws lines accordingly. I'm getting a very strange error message though and have few clues as to where it might be. This is the error message (doesn't always appear, sometimes just seg faults):

```
objc[2139]: Method cache corrupted. This may be a message to an invalid object, or a memory error somewhere else.
objc[2139]: unused 0x0, SEL 0x7fff8eb29c08, isa 0x7fff743d7c90, cache 0x7fff743d7ca0, buckets 0x10020c990, mask 0x3, occupied 0x1, wrap bucket 0x10020c990
objc[2139]: unused 0 bytes, buckets 64 bytes
objc[2139]: selector 'initialize'
objc[2139]: isa 'NSOrderedSet'
objc[2139]: Method cache corrupted.
```

When the program quits, Xcode points to the following code:

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Turtles", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

In this function:

```
/**
 Create SDL window and handle errors
 */
SDL_Window *createWindow() {

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Turtles", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    /*window = SDL_CreateWindow("Turtles", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);*/

    if(window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create window\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return window;
}
```

I don't think it's a problem with this function though as I've used it countless times before. I have no other clues as to where the real issue might be though. I've spent hours looking at every line in my program and using printf's to try to work it out, but no luck...

Here is a link to the full program (edit: new link, fixed some of the errors pointed out):

https://github.com/mtalu/turtles/commit/5bb499bfe80fe780bb1f632adee44e9a3df2d369

(Two c files and an input text file)

Any help / advise on how I might go about diagnosing this would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not enough memory allocated. In the function `getToken()` you allocate memory like this:

```
char *token = (char *) myMalloc(strlen(tempToken) * sizeof(char), "getToken");
```

or this:

```
char *token = (char *) malloc(strlen(tempToken) * sizeof(char));
```

and then copy the string

```
strcpy(token, tempToken);
```

but the memory allocated does not allow for the 0 string terminator. I would advise you to look through the rest of the code, to see if there are other instances of insufficient memory allocation.

Incidentally, in `myMalloc()` why have you cast the void pointer returned by `malloc()` to a void pointer? In any case, you should not cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: Cheers for this. Yeah, I had actually fixed the line that doesn't allocate enough memory to for the string, but forgot to commit before pushing. That line is now: char *token = (char *) malloc(strlen(tempToken) * sizeof(char) + 1); It doesn't fix the error unfortunately.

Comment: (@Daifel note that you should *still* not cast the return value of `malloc()`.)

Comment: @Daifel no, it should be `malloc((1+strlen(tempToken)) * sizeof(char));

Comment: The whole casting of pointers returned by malloc is because it's one of my lecturer's golden rules xD There was some debate about whether or not this was really necessary since void pointers are automatically converted (I think?), but the end decision is that we should carry on casting them.

Comment: (@Daifel Please leave that school. Now.)

Comment: @Daifel the problem commenters now have is this: how many other non-mistakes are there in your code?

Comment: Ah of course, you're right. Should have looked at that line more carefully. Fixed that now but still getting the error

Comment: I've pushed the version with these fixes to github and changed the link.

Comment: One other thing I forgot to mention (which makes me think you're right about it being some sort of memory allocation problem) is that the program works fine when there are only a few commands in the input text file. It's only only after a certain number of commands that the error appears.

Comment: So for example: { FD 30
LT 45
FD 30
LT 45 } works fine.

Answer (score 0):

in your main.c

followings are first calling code::

```
printf("Creating display\n");
Display *d;
d = getDisplay(d);
```

in your my_sdl_setup.c

```
Display *getDisplay(Display *newDisplay) 
{
    printf("Creating static display pointer\n");
    static Display *d;

    if(newDisplay) {
       printf("New display object provided, initializing!\n");
       printf("Mallocing space for display pointer\n");
       d = (Display *) malloc(sizeof(Display));
       if(d == NULL) {
          printf("Malloc failed in getDisplay\n");
       }

       printf("Initializing SDL\n");
       initializeSDL();
       .....
    }

    return d;
}
```

if main.c 's

```
Display *d;
```

In case of this you hope to compiler automatically initialize d to NULL.
then your code will works well on initialize SDL.
but d is not initialized , but NOT 0 (or NULL) 
then your SDL Init will not called correct time.

Also, Your question was About on Graphix Init issue. and logs.
So, first check this issue .

It's different compiler to debugging mode or release mode.

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out the problem was that I used `realloc` incorrectly:

I just changed:

```
tokens = (char **) realloc(tokens, sizeof(char *));
```

to:

```
tokens = (char **) realloc(tokens, sizeof(char *) * (*numberOfTokens + 1));
```

Now, thankfully, everything is working right.

Cheers for all the replies anyway!

Answer (score -3):

I recommend Display is setup well or not?
github linked code,

```
Display *d;
+    d = getDisplay(d);
```

in case of *d is not initialize well 
so you would try

```
Display *d = NULL;
```

and try it.

Comment: do you really, honestly think that this would help? `d` is assigned to immediately after its declaration. Initializing it to `NULL` would be dead code.

Comment: No! d is normally not initialized, It's uninitialized random,
If you see githubed source code. then you also agreed my comments.

And there's cache corruption is different 0x10 bytes. 
We need to check why alignment is in corrected.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  
    d will not deadcode!, you're wrong, getDisplay() function githubed! source code!!

Comment: nope, I'm not wrong. If you do this: `Display *d; d = getDisplay();` then `d` will be assigned the return value of `getDisplay()`. Since `d` is **not used** between its declaration and its assignment (since there's **no code** between its declaration and its assignment, as they are two consecutive statements), it's not used uninitialized, so there's no problem.

Comment: @Daifel first check display is well setuped and SDL is initialized well.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant d is not allocated,

just one time initialized, followings are function.
if d is newDisplay value is not correctly allocated , but value is not 0 (NULL) then, this program will not init sdl init code , proper sequence and time.

Display *getDisplay(Display *newDisplay) {
    printf("Creating static display pointer\n");
    static Display *d;
    
    if(newDisplay) {
       printf("New display object provided, initializing!\n");
        printf("Mallocing space for display pointer\n");
        d = (Display *) malloc(sizeof(Display));

Comment: and? it's not being dereferenced… you are hopelessly confusing `d = getDisplay()` with `*d = getDisplay()`…

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant this is not a reference or dereferencing issue.
just think as check the code flow first,
normally debugging mode of build, newDisplay argument value will be normally NULL, then getDisplay() function initialized, on time.
but, runtime building then we can't assure newDisplay argument is null , value will be random assigned address.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant First look at the github source code.

Comment: @ cpplover - Slw Essencial: Unfortunately I don't really understand your solution. Setting Display * to NULL just prevents it from getting initialized. The point of the getDisplay function is that it gets initialized once when called with a Display * and can then be called with NULL to return the initialized display object

Comment: @Daifel I've checked your code's ambuiguity. another post I explained.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant `getDisplay()` is taking an uninitialised argument, as the next answer from "cpplover - Slw Essencial" shows.